# Convolution2D vs Conv2D in Keras library, in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

Is there any documentation on whether these are the same or different modules and the differences between these?

```
keras.layers.Conv2D
keras.layers.Convolution2D
keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D
keras.layers.convolutional.Convolution2D
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're aliases for the same functionality. The reason behind this is related to the new Keras 2 API, which tries to give users some time to migrate their code to the new one, and to use the shorter one with different parameters. The other aliases eventually are going to be deprecated, since when using old Keras API shows warnings.

See [Keras code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/convolutional.py#L2099)

Comment: Thanks, but what is the difference between `keras.layers` and `keras.layers.convolutional` then?

Comment: They are the same. Take a look at __init__.py (1), it imports all convolutional classes from convolutional.py. The legacy interface parameters are still defined in (2)

(1) https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/__init__.py#L10

(2) https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/convolutional.py#L424